# iMX8M Plus UART problem with switched signals in recovery mode

Tags: debugging, uart, imx8

I hope someone is able to help me out.
We designed a custom base board for the iMX8M Plus Dart module from Variscite. The problem is that somehow the pins of the debug UART1 are exchanged when loading the u-boot binary in recovery mode.
The strange thing on this is, that when I put the CPU module into the development board from Variscite and load the exact same binary the UART pins are correctly connected and I can see the debug output in the terminal.

Maybe, u-boot is checking some special boot configuration and is deciding if the pins should be in DTE or DCE mode. Is anybody aware of such a hardware config?

Btw. the boot mode config on the iMX8M Plus module of Variscite is just done with the 4 hardware config pins BOOT_MODE[0:3], right?